# Missing values in Org macro replacement

Tags: org-mode, org-export

The Org Manual says: *"The ‘keyword’ macro collects all values from NAME keywords throughout the buffer, separated with white space."* (https://orgmode.org/manual/Macro-Replacement.html). Despite that, with both latex and html exporters, I got only "First Author" in the exported document. This is curious since both \author from latex and metadata author from html shows "First Author Second Author" as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

```
#+TITLE: Foo

#+AUTHOR: First Author
#+AUTHOR: Second Author

* Testing macros
The title is: {{{title}}}. The authors are {{{author}}} or {{{keyword(AUTHOR)}}}.
```

Comment: You might want to report a bug with `M-x org-submit-bug-report`.  AFAICT, the documentation is (mostly -  with the exception of the `keyword` expansion you quote above) silent on what happens if you have two such directives and the code is inconsistent in its behavior: as you mention, having two `"#+AUTHOR:` directives does two different things when you export: both end up in the "actual" title but only one in the macro expansion. OTOH, if you have two title directives, then both are added to the "actual" title, *as well as* to the macro expansion. That qualifies as a bug in my book.

Comment: Thanks @NickD. Indeed, it sounds a bug.